# OnStart or onWindowFocusChange called first?

Tags: android, android-layout

So I've got this code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
super.onCreate(bundle);
...
setContentView(R.layout.article_layout);
TextView titleView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.article_title);
TextView content = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.article_content);
formatArticle(titleView, content);
....
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
....
code that deals with placing images in formatted article.
}
```

In this code, I have a pair of textviews created with a default font size and margins.  I then pass them to `formatArticle()` to adjust the font and margins to a users preferences that they've stored.  In `onWindowsFocusChanged()`, I inline the images to the article by calling `getWidth()` of the textview and resizing the bitmap accordingly.

However, whenever this code runs, the bitmaps only size themselves to the default textview size.  Is `onWindowFocusChanged()` called before `formatArticle()`, or do I have another problem.  If `onWindowFocusChanged()` is called first, is there a way I can have it wait for `formatArticle()` to complete?

Comment: Why don't you just put the "code that deals with placing images in formatted article" in `onCreate(...)`?

Comment: In onCreate, the textview hasn't been laid out yet, so `textView.getWidth()` returns 0.  The best solution I've found to fix that is calling it in `onWindowFocusChanged()`

Comment: "In onCreate, the textview hasn't been laid out yet," - Both `TextViews` that you pass to `formatArticle(...)` must have been created by the inflation process of `setContentView(...)` so I assume what you mean by "laid out" is what happens in that `formatArticle(...)`? If that's the case then put the "code that deals with placing images in formatted article" in the `formatArticle(...)` method. I don't really understand why you'd use `onWindowFocusChanged(...)`.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant.  There is a time that the text views have been inflated, but have a height and width of 0.  If you do an SO or Google search, you'll see this is a common problem, with one solution being to move the `getWidth()` to `onWindowFocusChanged()`.  `formatArticle()` just changes the padding and text size values, it does not actually give the textview a width. The textview seems to get it's width almost as it's shown on screen. Even `onResume()` is too early.  As far as I know, `onWindowFocusChanged()` is the latest automatic call I can make before the user sees a problem.